# Unity Netcode for GameObjects Command Pattern with RPC

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, networking, multiplayer, abstract-data-type

I'm trying to implement a command pattern to use by sending a command via rpc but can't figure out how to send it correctly.

The command is set up as such

```
abstract class Command
{
   public virtual void Execute() { }
}

class ConcreteCommand:Command
{
//some fields (all of which need to be serializable)
//some constructor
//override Execute()
}
```

I want to be able to send any command through the rpc but havn't been able to figure out how to send it.

I have tried making Command inherit INetworkSerializable and having each subclass override NetworkSerialize but got an error saying "MissingMethodException: Default constructor not found for type Command"

I have tried using reflection

```
typename = ConcreteCommand.GetType().FullName;
parameters = ?????
//send via rpc
Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(typeName), parameters);
```

but can't figure out how to send an object[] for the parameters (assuming all parameters are serializable)

Edit to clear up any confusion:

- I have a class that generates Concrete Commands.
- I have a function that accepts Abstract Commands.
- This function needs to send the Abstract command to the server via rpc and the server needs to recreate the same Abstract Command (same subclass with the same parameters) so it can call Execute().

How can I do this? The methods I've tried have not worked.

Comment: tbh, this is not how ive seen any rpc done in netcode.   the clients should call a serverrpc perhaps to trigger it, but the server then calls a clientrpc for it to happen on the relevant clients.

Comment: I originally started the project having it be like that but couldn't find a good solution for my particular use case. The clients are doing most of the calculating in code that I want decoupled from networking, then is telling the server "This is the results", to which the server verifies and stores in a queue to execute sequentially and asynchronous to the rest of the program.

Comment: well, anything you do clientside is open for abuse by the usual suspects. However, you can still calculate locally and send to server and use a network variable

Comment: I'm not worried about client side abuse in this case since anything they could abuse in these calculations, they should already be able to do in software (it's a spellcasting system that is similar to programming). 
I'm not sure I understand your suggestion however. Network variables still need to be serializable, so this would be the exact same problem as above no?

Comment: not really, as it depends what the variable is.. as you havent mentioned other than "calculations"  .. so, is your question as it appears how to be at the end how to make an array of object ?

Comment: I just need to be able to serialize any ConcreteCommand (which has some number of serializable fields) to send it to the server as a Command. The server treats all commands the same (The server essentially just calls Execute and does some verifying). The calculations are irrelevant to the question (and have not been fully implemented yet), just that the client runs them and returns results in the form of Commands. object[] was just one strategy i used to try and solve the problem with reflection.

Comment: then mark it serializable ?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I've edited the post to be clearer.

Comment: my last comment still seems to apply

Comment: I still get the error "MissingMethodException: Default constructor not found for type Command." I have Command marked as Serialiazable, It extends INetworkSerializable, and the subclass overrides NetworkSerialize.

Comment: so add a constructor?

Comment: Update: I think I got something working. Will post what I found when I figure out what I did. Also you can't add a constructor to an abstract class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error (and mostly error) this is what I came up with.

```
public abstract class Command: INetworkSerializable
{
    public virtual void Execute() { }
    public abstract void NetworkSerialize<T>(BufferSerializer<T> serializer) where T : IReaderWriter;
    public abstract void Send(NetworkObjectReference netObj);
    protected void Recieve(Command command, NetworkObjectReference netObj) { /*Do stuff here*/ }
}

public class ConcreteCommand: Command
{
    public string field = "Default value";
    public ConcreteCommand(string field) { this.field = field; }
    public override void Execute() { /*Do stuff here*/ }
    public override void NetworkSerialize<T>(BufferSerializer<T> serializer)
    {
        serializer.SerializeValue(ref field);
    }
    public override void Send(NetworkObjectReference netObj) { CommandServerRpc(this, netObj); }
    [ServerRpc] public void CommandServerRpc(ConcreteCommand command, NetworkObjectReference netObj) { Recieve(command, netObj); }
}
```

The client code only needs to call Command.Send and the server can do it's thing with the Command regardless of the subtype and with all the correct parameters.